# Typescript compiler weird behaviour when interface doesn't fit

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I'm not sure how to phrase this but I get this weird behaviour of the Typescript compiler when I use an interface in some cases.

For example, this works great, as intended. No compiler error, nothing.

```js
interface Bar {
  letter: 'a' | 'b';
}

declare class Foo {
  constructor(bars: Bar[]);
}

const foo = new Foo([
  {
    "letter": "a"
  },
  {
    "letter": "b"
  }
]);
```

But if I add an unnecessary parameter in one of the `Bar` like here:

```js
const foo = new Foo([
  {
    "letter": "a"
  },
  {
    "letter": "b"
    "what": 175875,
  }
]);
```

Then the compiler throw this unexpected error on **both** of my `letter` params:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
```

Am I missing something or is that some sort of compiler issue?

Comment: Basically, you're telling it that you're passing an array of `Bar`, but then passing something in the array that is not a `Bar`, so TypeScript complains about the whole array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a compiler error, it has been like this since TypeScript 1.6, see this: [Breaking Changes | Strict object literal assignment checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#strict-object-literal-assignment-checking)

what you need is to tell typescript the interface can have more properties like this:

```
interface Bar {
  letter: 'a' | 'b';
  [x: string]: any;
}
```